# Is it a legal notation: Foo &foo = Bar;

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};

Foo &foo = Bar; // without ()
```

I wonder, Is it a legal notation? And if it is legal, could you give some details? Something like, Why it's legal? Or, What is the origin of such a notation?

**EDIT:** I cannot compile this code. But I met a code like that and wanted to know whether such a notation is allowed (probably just my compiler doesn't support this notation). I'm having some uncertainty since the following notation is quite legal: `Foo *pFoo = new Bar;`

Comment: With or without the parenthesis that code is illegal. What is your real concern? Why are you interested in this?

Comment: What is it with the upvoters?? The question makes no sense, and the user did not even take the effort of trying to run the code (either variant) through a compiler... yet there are 2 upvotes?

Comment: I don't think `struct Foo {}` is legal either.

Comment: Assigning a class to an object tends to be a mistake at the best of times. When you do 'struct Foo', you're declaring a struct type called Foo, so this code is trying to assign a class type (Foo) to an object type Foo()

Comment: @David: I originally upvoted the question because I thought it was clear what the intention of the OP was. I simply overread all the errors in there. However, you are right, such questions should not be encouraged or rewarded.

Comment: @nos: A different question that asked why `const Foo &foo = Bar()` compiles with the `()` and doesn't without it *makes sense* as it shows that there is a misunderstanding of the meaning of `Bar` or `Bar()`, but from the question you cannot infer what the confusion comes from, since both alternatives are *illegal*. Also, the question *is this legal?* when any and all compilers would reject it shows that it was not tested, compared to *shouldn't this be legal?* or *why is this illegal*, *why does this not compile*?...

Comment: @nos: I don't by the rationale of *can be fixed with a couple of keystrokes*. Or do you consider the question *is this legal? `int (){}`* a proper question? it is missing just 4 characters: `main`

Comment: This serial upvoter problem is a big nuissance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot assign an class Name to a reference/object. It is neither syntactically valid nor does it make any sense.
2. You cannot bind a reference to a temporary(rvalue), So following is illegal too:

   `Foo &foo = Bar();`
3. You can bind a temporary(rvalue) to an const reference, So following is legal:

   `const Foo &foo = Bar();`

The C++ standard specifically allows the 3.

Answer (score 3):

It should be a compiler error.

> g++: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token

`Bar` is a name of `class` and it cannot be assigned to reference / variable. Even with putting `()` it will not compile, unless you make `foo` a `const Foo&`.

Comment: Neither would it compile with the `()`... no problem with your answer, but the question is *not* a question...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I have updated that part of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The code as presented is not legal because `Bar` is the name of a class, not a variable.

The following, however, is:

```
struct Foo {}
struct Bar : Foo {}

Bar fooBar;
Foo &foo = fooBar; // without ()
```

It is legal because `Bar` is a `Foo`, so you're just giving a different name to your variable `fooBar`.

Note however that `foo`, although an alias for `fooBar`, will interpret the location as a `Foo` object.

This means the following:

```
struct Foo { int x; };       //note semicolons after struct declaration
struct Bar : Foo { int y; };

Bar fooBar;
fooBar.y = 2;
fooBar.x = 3;
Foo &foo = fooBar;
int aux;
aux = foo.x; // aux == 3
aux = foo.y; // compile error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a reference. So as already mentioned this is not legal regardless of the parentheses.

Comment: You can bind a value to a `const`-reference.

Comment: This is initialisation, not assignment.