# Foo &foo = Bar() is legal or is it a compiler issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, visual-c++-2010

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};

Foo &foo = Bar(); // without const
```

As it is written in the answers and comments to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953484/is-it-a-legal-notation-foo-foo-bar), I cannot assign a rvalue to a reference. However, I can compile this code (MSVC++ 2010) without error or warning. Is it a known problem of my compiler?

Comment: The fact that you can bind a temporary to a non-const reference is a known "feature" of MSVC.

Comment: what is the purpose of the paranteses after Bar? shouldn't it be just Bar?

Comment: @MartinKristiansen no. Why would it? What would that do?

Comment: @RMartinhoFermandes: you are right.

Comment: If MSVC is not complaining that means you haven't turned the warning level up enough. With the right setting it warns of a *non-standard extension being used* when binding an r-value to a non-const reference.

Comment: @Praetorian, Thanks. I believe it's the answer to my question. Do you mind to write it as an answer, so I could submit it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it a legal notation: Foo &foo = Bar;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953484/is-it-a-legal-notation-foo-foo-bar)

Comment: @sad_man, yes I found it. I'm waiting for someone to have written it as an answer to submit it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a temporary value to the reference. It is temporary because, here, `Bar()` acts like a function that returns a `Bar` instance which will evaporate at the and of the expression scope, which is here the end of line. It is highly dangerous and illegal, because dereferencing the `foo` creates an undefined behaviour. I have no idea why MSVC++ allows this "feature" which must be a solid error.

With warning level 4 (/W4) you will get

```
warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'Bar' to 'Bar &'
```

You should always write code with warning level 4.
Lastly, @KerrekSB's answer is better than mine, you should choose his' as an answer.

Comment: So, what's the answer? Is it possible to bind to non-constant references in MSVC as an extension? And if yes, how does one disable the warning?

Comment: @KerrekSB Since it is a level 4 warning (/W4) it is disabled by default for projects created using the wizard; the default setting is /W3. IMHO that needs to be a lower level warning since it can lead to non-portable code.

Comment: @KerrekSB, The answer is that such a behavior is a non-standard extension of MSVC compiler. And Praetorian is right: firstly I compiled with /W3 option

Answer (score 10):

Temporaries do not bind to non-constant references. That's just the way the language is designed.

While there's in principle no technical obstruction to permitting non-constant access to temporaries, that would almost always be poor design, and quite often flat-out logically erroneous, so the standard just doesn't allow it. If you feel the need to modify a temporary, you should rethink why you want to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). It's useful. However, the answer doesn't explain the problem in my case.

Comment: @Loom: Yes, I understand. I think I knew vaguely that MSVC allowed this as an extension... well, good to know for sure :-) Just bear in mind that this is not standard-conforming and thus not portable, and quite possible a sign of a design flaw somewhere.